# Emberjs (link-to HasMany) Error while loading route: TypeError: Cannot call method 'resolve' of undefined

Tags: ember.js

I am trying to set model of a route(not nested) but with relationship belong to with setupController

Here is my [**JSBIN**](http://emberjs.jsbin.com/ORujoCo/1/edit)
i.e company hasMany Contacts
from companies list page I have directly linked to contacts page (want flow that ways)

I want to use the company model to get its contacts list but I am getting error

```
Error while loading route: TypeError: Cannot call method 'resolve' of undefined
```

**Heres my Router**

```
App.Router.map(function() {
  this.resource('companies',{path:'/'});
  this.resource('company',{path:'/company/:company_id'});
  this.resource('contacts',{path:'/company/:id/contacts'});  
});
```

**This is what I am doing**

```
App.ContactsRoute = Em.Route.extend({
  setupController: function(controller, model) {
    console.log(model.get('contacts')); //This line gives error
    //controller.set('model',model.get('contacts'));
  }
});
```

**The MODEL**

```
App.Company = DS.Model.extend({
    name: DS.attr('string'),
    contacts: DS.hasMany('Contact')
});

App.Company.FIXTURES = [{
    id: 1,
    name: 'company 1',
    contacts: ['1']
}, {
    id: 2,
    name: 'company 2',
    contacts: ['1', '2']

}];

App.Contact = DS.Model.extend({
    name: DS.attr('string'),
    company: DS.belongsTo('Company')

});
App.Contact.FIXTURES = [{
    id: 1,
    name: 'employee 1',
    company: 1   
}, {
    id: 2,
    name: 'employee 2',
    company: 2
}];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Updated Fiddle](http://emberjs.jsbin.com/ORujoCo/3/)

I updated the fiddle for you and changed a few things. To me, it seemed more logical to add `contacts` as a route of the resource `company` instead of a separate resource.

I also made the company model `async`, so it waits for all models to be loaded before actually rendering everything

Take a look and feel free to ask questions if you don't fully understand the solution.

Comment: Hey thanks for the solution. I am still in learning phase and my choice between resource and route was anything that is a model (Company, Contacts) has to be resource and anything that is done on model like (new, edit) should be route...may be I got the wrong idea...currently going through solution will ask if I did not full understand thanks again.